# Website PHP form returns code instead of submitting

Tags: php, forms

I've been having a problem with my code. I have a small and simple form on the bottom of my website. If I try and fill it in and submit, it either returns the code or gives me a error 500 (if I try other solutions). I'm hosting on 000webhost if it helps. The rest of the website is made in Bootstrap.

I'm pretty noob at php, and I'm not at all a web developer, so sorry if I'm doing stuff completely wrong.

```
<?php
/*ini_set('display_errors', 1);*/

$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_from = 'my_email';
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
"Name:\n $name"
"Email:\n $visitor_email"
"Subject:\n $subject"
"Message:\n $message".

$to = "my_email";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

Comment: **$email_body** is completely wrong builded.

Comment: What is the extension of the page ?

Comment: I got the php code from a website, so I just hoped/assumed that it was ok. Could you help me or send a link to a website that does it right?

Comment: The page is called 'php.ini', if that's what you mean

Comment: in your form, you have certainly something like `<form action="...">` What is inside the doubles quotes for `action="..."`

Comment: I have it like this: <form action="php/php.ini" method="post" role="form">

Comment: @Stefankloosterman did your form and php mail scripts all in same php file?

Comment: @DroidDev The form is in my index.html, with the <form action="php/php.ini" method="post" role="form"> referring to my php code(all of the above).

Comment: Where is the php code available. In which file and path for that?

Comment: I have a php.ini in a php folder, which is in the same folder as my index.html

Comment: I would never ever build an email without using an appropriate library. Any discrepancy from RFCs will make the email look like spam in transit. Crafting an email manually WILL make the email trigger a lot of warnings.Even n00b's should learn PEAR. For example Mail-Mime (https://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/docs/latest/Mail_Mime/Mail_mime.html) will help. A lot!

Answer (score 0):

Missing some points, also a semicolon to end a line of code.

```
<?php
    /*ini_set('display_errors', 1);*/

     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
     $subject = $_POST['subject'];
     $message = $_POST['message'];

     $email_from = 'my_email';
     $email_subject = "New Form submission";
     $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
     "Name:\n $name".
     "Email:\n $visitor_email".
     "Subject:\n $subject".
     "Message:\n $message";

     $to = "my_email";
     $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
     $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
     mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!; it still only returns code sadly

Comment: uncomment first line, delete these characters /* And */ . This function print on screen error codes. Send newly the contact form for to indicate, what error is it that shows